# what is the difference between operating system and meta-operating system

Tags: operating-system, ros

Recently I heard the term *meta-operating system* while I was learning ros. Could you please help me to differentiate between *operating system* and *meta-operating system*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What ROS is and is not is best explained in [this paper](http://www.robotics.stanford.edu/~ang/papers/icraoss09-ROS.pdf).

To cite the [intodruction](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction) at ros.org:

> It provides the services you would expect from an operating system, including hardware abstraction, low-level device control, implementation of commonly-used functionality, message-passing between processes, and package management. It also provides tools and libraries for obtaining, building, writing, and running code across multiple computers.

You'll also find a good explanation in [this wiki.](https://github.com/uscrs-art/uscrs-art/wiki/ROS-Tutorial-4.-ROS-Overview%3a-Nodes,-Messages-and-Services) The basic difference is that a meta operating system is built on top of the operating system and allows different processes (nodes) to communicate with each other at runtime.